# Iframe Embeded Youtube Videos Events Tracking - Ensighten Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I want to track Events like Play Video, Pause Video, Start Video & End Video in Google Analytics using Ensighten for iframe Embeded Youtube Videos?

I have already enabled the YoutubejsAPI in the iframe embeded Youtube URL parameter as recommended by Google i.e ‘enablejsapi=1’.  I also tried to call their predefined onPlayerStateChange() function using ‘event’ property as recommended.

Below mentioned code snippet for reference (courtesy: lunametrics.com)

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
 
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
var video = 'PoljF9Zqv3Y';
    video.h = '271'; //video iframe height
    video.w = '640'; //video iframe width
 
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('videoFrame', {
    height: video.h,
    width: video.w,
    videoId: video,
    events: {
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  switch (event.data) {
    case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
      if (cleanTime() === 0) {
        // console.log('started ' + cleanTime());
          ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'started', video);
      } else {
        // console.log('playing ' + cleanTime())
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'played', 'v: ' + video + ' | t: ' + cleanTime());
      }
      break;
    case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
      if (player.getDuration() - player.getCurrentTime() !== 0) {
        // console.log('paused' + ' @ ' + cleanTime());
        ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'paused', 'v: ' + video + ' | t: ' + cleanTime());
      }
      break;
    case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
      // console.log('ended ');
      ga('send', 'event', 'video', 'ended', video);
      break;
  }
}

// utility
function cleanTime(){
    return Math.round(player.getCurrentTime());
}
```

Evenif, it is not firing any event in my real time GA Report.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look to how [Komito Analytics](https://komito.net/) does. See `init_` function in the [source code](https://github.com/Datamart/Komito/blob/master/src/komito/trackers/media/youtube.js).